# HTML5 Time Control Binding

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-5

How to bind time value `10:00 AM` get from `DateField.ToShortTimeString()` to `Html5 Time Control`.

Here my binding:

[image]

it gives following error:

[image]

Comment: Your question needs to include your code, not an image of it. What is typeof RequestTime?

Comment: Assuming its `TimeSpan`, then remove the 2nd parameter - the browser will display the AM or PM as appropriate (e.g. `10:00:00` will display as 10:00 AM and `22:00:00` will display as 10:00 PM

Comment: Thanks @StephenMuecke, its working when i convert RequestTime from string to Timespan.

Answer (score 0):

I think AM with 10:00 is creating that problem so it would be good if you tried to get only "HH:mm" or "HH:mm:ss.SSS" from your Model

```
var date = DateTime.Now;
date.Hour;
date.Minute;
```

If you are still getting error then please show screen shot of model.
Thanks!

Comment: you are right, but i need full time to be bind with Am section